# fixing an Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I created this loop that only works the first time and then I recieve an Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception.

```
for(int a=0; a<pkcode.length;a++){
  for(int b=0;b<trainercode.length;a++){
    if(pkcode[a]==trainercode[b]){
      w=a+1;
      v=b+1;
      System.out.println("Your egg(s) that match with trainers are:");
      System.out.println("egg #" +w+ ": " + pkcode[a] + " matches with trainer #" +v+ ": " + trainercode[b]);
        }
  }
```

}

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int b=0;b<trainercode.length;a++){
```

should be

```
for(int b=0;b<trainercode.length;b++){
```

You're incrementing the wrong value (inner loop uses `b` but increments `a`).

This will make you have an infinite loop in the inner loop (`b` is never incremented thus it never reaches the end condition) and it will reach your `a` twice as fast and get out of bounds on `pkcode[a]`.